# How to get a new input in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

This is a snippet of my code. I want to break the loop if a user messages on discord "??." I know the problem is that its not taking a new input and basing the command of the first send I dont know how to fix it in discord.py however. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
      for i in range(1000):
        await message.channel.send(message.content.replace("!spam",""))
        if client.wait_for("message") == "??":
          print("stopped")
          break
        else:
          continue
```

Answer (score 1):

The `client.wait_for` method is a coroutine so you need to `await` it. It also returns a `discord.Message` instance, not a string.

```py
for i in range(1000):
    await message.channel.send(message.content.replace("!spam", ""))
    msg = await client.wait_for("message")
    if msg.content == "??":
        break
```

You might wanna add a `check` to the `wait_for` method